# Structure groups of $G$-bundles and $G$-associated bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

Take a $G$-bundle to be a fiber bundle with typical fiber $F$ whose transition functions take values in the structure group $G$ = Aut($F$). Based on this definition alone, I would assume that the tangent bundle $TM$ with typical fiber $\Bbb{R}^d$ has structure group Aut($\Bbb{R}^d$) = GL($d$, $\Bbb{R}$), and that the frame bundle $FM$ with typical fiber GL($d$, $\Bbb{R}$) has structure group Aut(GL($d$, $\Bbb{R}$)). So, the structure groups are clearly different.

However, $TM$ and $FM$ are GL($d$, $\Bbb{R}$)-associated, which entails that they share the *exact same* transition functions. One can see this by transforming a pointwise trivialization of $FM$:

$$\psi^B_{FM, p}([e_i]_{i=1}^d) = (\psi^B_{TM, p}(e_i))^d_{i=1} = (g^{BA}_p\psi^A_{TM,p}(e_i))_{i=1}^d = g^{BA}_p(\psi^A_{TM,p}(e_i))_{i=1}^d = g^{BA}_p\psi^A_{FM,p}([e_i]^d_{i=1})$$

To clarify the notation, we have a pointwise trivialization on $FM$ over $p \in U^X$ given by $\psi^X_{FM,p}: F_pM \to \text{GL}(d)$, a pointwise trivialization on $TM$ over $p \in U^X$ given by $\psi^X_{TM,p}: T_pM \to \Bbb{R}^d$, and a GL($d$)-valued transition function $g^{BA}_p$ transforming a local trivialization over $U^A$ to a local trivialization over $U^B$.

It seems as if the above two paragraphs contradict each other, where treating $TM$ and $FM$ as separate $G$-bundles leads to them having distinct structure groups, while treating them as GL($d$)-associated immediately implies that they have coinciding structure groups. What is my mistake here? I'm definitely missing something.

Comment: What do you mean by $\operatorname{Aut}(F)$? For a smooth fiber bundle, $F$ is a smooth manifold, not a group, so $\operatorname{Aut}(F) = \operatorname{Diff}(F)$. In particular, $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is not $GL(d, \mathbb{R})$. However, for a vector bundle, you can reduce the structure group to $GL(d, \mathbb{R})$. Likewise, for a smooth principal $G$-bundle, you can reduce the structure group from $\operatorname{Diff}(G)$ to $G$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese So then my issue is the definition of $G$-bundle? Namely, it should be a bundle whose stucture group can be reduced from Aut($F$) to $G$. How does one go about showing that we can reduce the structure group from Diff($G$) to $G$ for a principal $G$-bundle?

Comment: What you call a $G$-bundle is called a fibre bundle with fibre $F$ and structure group $G$. Transition functions arise when you compare two trivialisations. For a vector bundle, the trivialisations have to be linear in each fiber, which is why the structure group is $GL(d, \mathbb{R})$. For a principal $G$-bundle, the trivialisations are $G$-equivariant, and this forces the transition functions $t_{ij}$ to be $G$-equivariant, i.e. they satisfy $t_{ij}(hg) = t_{ij}(h)g$. It then follows that $t_{ij}(g) = t_{ij}(eg) = t_{ij}(e)g$ which is left multiplication by $t_{ij}(e) \in G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue in your definition of a $G$-bundle. In particular, it is not the case that $G=\operatorname{Aut}(F)$. A $G$-bundle is typically defined as a collection of all of the following pieces of data:

- A fiber bundle $\pi:E\to M$.
- The typical fiber $F$ of $E$.
- A group $G$.
- A left action of $G$ on $F$, i.e. a map $\theta:G\to\operatorname{Aut}(F)$. (This action is often required to be faithful.)
- A $G$-atlas $\mathcal{A}$ of $E$, i.e. a set of local trivializations which cover $E$ whose transition functions are $G$-valued.

To obtain the principal $G$-bundle associated with a $G$-bundle, we can replace the typical fiber $F$ with $G$, and the action $\theta$ with the left action of $G$ on itself. The allows us to construct a unique (up to isomorphism) bundle with the same transition functions.

Comment: Many thanks. So in the case of the frame bundle, we provide in its *definition* that it has structure group $G$ = GL($d$, $\Bbb{R}$). This isn't something that we determine afterwards?

Comment: @gian You're welcome. You can't determine the structure group given the fiber bundle alone; it's an extra piece of data you have to add. Generally speaking, there are multiple inequivalent ways of equipping a fiber bundle with a structure group.